# Conduction and valence band confusion

Tags: semiconductor-physics

After spending quite a lot at understanding ,I could still not help myself in clearing this doubt-In free electron sea model used in electrodynamics the actual motion of electrons causes current to flow but as we move to band theory how the simple jump causes current to flow?Simply put, why an electron jump from valence to conduction band causes a current to flow?

Comment: You've basically asked the same question 4 previous times: [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/527866/22927), [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/527918/22927), [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/527985/22927), and [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/528385/22927). If you don't get a good answer, we expect you to edit your question to improve it, not just keep re-posting it. Try to focus it down more so we get a better idea of what you do understand, and where your understanding ends, so we can give you a useful answer.

Comment: Can you phrase a proper question? We would like to know what exactly you are looking for and what you find unsatisfactory in the current answers across your 5 questions.

Comment: user3518839 In a direct question how can one harmonise the free electrons sea model  with band theory

Answer (score 0):

> why an electron jump from valence to conduction band causes a current to flow?

An electron jumping from the valence band to the conduction band doesn't cause current to flow.

But it does mean there is now a pair of mobile carriers in the lattice, so **if there is an electric field** a current **can** flow.

Comment: Could you please elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

> Simply put, why an electron jump from valence to conduction band causes a current to flow?

It can conduct electricity resulting in a current but it doesn't "cause" current to flow.

This is possible because in a metallic solid, the valence electrons are completely de-localized over the entire bulk metal and hence the electrons aren't strongly attracted to the ions (*kernels*).

The electrons (in the bulk) are also less strongly bound to an ion than in a single isolated atom of that metal.

All these factors make it possible for it to move easily in response to an applied electric field.

Comment: Then what we mean by conduction band?

Comment: user8718165 I have already visited the webpage but I could not exactly define conduction band

Comment: Does this mean that electrons in conduction band are free?